# Transitive dependencies coming from provided scope dependency

Tags: java, maven, vaadin, dependency-management, maven-dependency

I have added `vaadin-client-compiler` dependency as a `provided` scope dependency in my vaadin application pom.

As I have read, `provided` dependency is not transitive, so the dependencies of `vaadin-client-compiler` should become dependencies of my webapp.

But, I found dependencies of `vaadin-client-compiler` (commons-lang3-3.1.jar)  inside my WEB-INF/lib directory.

Also, these dependencies are shown in `mvn dependency:tree` output as well.

```
[INFO] |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:sources:1.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO] +- com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiler:jar:7.6.4:provided
[INFO] |  +- com.vaadin:vaadin-sass-compiler:jar:0.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.yahoo.platform.yui:yuicompressor:jar:2.4.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- rhino:js:jar:1.7R2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
................................................
.................................................
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
```

**Question**: Why did dependencies of a `provided` scope dependency became dependencies of my webapp?

Comment: Is the jar available in the final package ?

Comment: @VinayVeluri, yes. As I have mentioned, the dependency jars available in `WEB-INF/lib`.

Comment: Did you perhaps build your web app before making it `provided`? What happens if you try to run `mvn clean package`, does it stil show up in your lib dir?

Comment: @Morfic, I did a clean build before checking.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, according to official [Maven Dependency Mediation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html), the `provided` scope would bring in its transitive dependencies as following:

- Transitive dependencies in `compile` scope > would be fetched as `provided` scope
- Transitive dependencies in `provided` scope > ignored
- Transitive dependencies in `runtime` scope > would be fetched as `provided` scope
- Transitive dependencies in `test` scope > ignored

Hence, transitive dependencies of a `provided` dependency would either be ignored or be imported as `provided` as well and as such no part of the final packaged `war`.

Adding the following dependency to a sample project:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>7.6.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Would lead to the following, executing:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=com.vaadin
```

We would have as part of the output:

```
[INFO] \- com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiler:jar:7.6.4:provided
[INFO]    +- com.vaadin:vaadin-shared:jar:7.6.4:provided
[INFO]    +- com.vaadin:vaadin-server:jar:7.6.4:provided
[INFO]    +- com.vaadin:vaadin-client:jar:7.6.4:provided
[INFO]    +- com.vaadin:vaadin-sass-compiler:jar:0.9.13:provided
[INFO]    \- com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiler-deps:jar:1.2.0:provided
```

Perfectly consistent with the documentation.

**However**, if we add to the `pom.xml` file the following:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
            <version>7.6.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Note: we are overriding the scope of one of its transitive dependencies to `compile`.

Re-executing the previous command we would have:

```
[INFO] \- com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiler:jar:7.6.4:provided
[INFO]    +- com.vaadin:vaadin-shared:jar:7.6.4:compile
[INFO]    +- com.vaadin:vaadin-server:jar:7.6.4:compile
[INFO]    +- com.vaadin:vaadin-client:jar:7.6.4:provided
[INFO]    +- com.vaadin:vaadin-sass-compiler:jar:0.9.13:compile
[INFO]    \- com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiler-deps:jar:1.2.0:provided
```

Which means: the transitive dependency `vaadin-server` is still brought in by `vaadin-client-compiler`, but its scope is now at `compile` as per dependency management.

Hence, you should:

- Check whether your `pom.xml` defines any `dependencyManagement` section
- Check whether your parent pom or any pom in the hierarchy would do so, executing `mvn help:effective-pom -Doutput=full-pom.xml` would definitely help
- Check whether any active profile would also influence the build, executing `mvn help:active-profiles` would also help

Comment: @LahiruChandima did you fix this issue? did this answer help?

Comment: I think there is no dependency management or profile specific behavior here.
This is a standard case also described here https://stackoverflow.com/q/55147019/1034782
And registered on maven issue tracker here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6607
Maybe this is not a "bug", but it seems this is not documented anywhere !

Answer (score 0):

The "non-transitivity" of provided dependencies is tricky. It only means that the provided dependencies of your dependencies are not pulled. On the other hand, compile dependencies of provided dependencies are pulled (as you have experienced). The full truth is in the table shown in:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html