# Transitive dependencies brought by provided scope and compile scope are computed as compile scope

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

We face an issue when a same `artifact-X` is transitively brought by a `dependency-1` with **provided** scope, and another `dependency-2` with **default (compile)** scope.
This `artifact-X` will be computed as **compile** scope, while we expect it to be explicitly provided by `dependency-1`.

For example, `dependency-1` pom contains:

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

`dependency-2` pom contains:

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Assembly project pom contains:

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <!-- do not include dependencies already provided by module-1 at runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>module-1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- get dependencies required by module-2 runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>module-2</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

But a `mvn dependency:tree` on assembly project will output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.0:tree (show-app-dependencies) @ module-3 ---
[INFO] com.company:module-3:pom:1.0
[INFO] +- com.company:module-1:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.1:provided
[INFO] \- com.company:module-2:jar:1.0:compile
```

And we can see the artifact `commons-lang3:jar:3.7` which come from dependency-1 is now at **compile** scope. Note that we don't use any `<dependencyManagement>` here.

This is very confusing, and leads to duplicate libraries in runtime classpath when `dependency-1` is effectively provided in classpath of `dependency-2` runtime (for example by an application server).

Moreover, based on Maven documentation about dependency mediation/scope, the transitive dependencies that are provided should be always **ommited**.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

It seems to be a bug, that maven-3.6 does not handle, which is a shame !

However, as our goal is simply to package ONLY the libraries defined as compile/runtime (and ignore all the provided ones, and their transitives), how to achieve this using dependency management, or if impossible, using maven-assembly-plugin ??

Comment: Registered as an issue here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6607

Comment: Note that the goal is to avoid managing conflicts manually each time the provided dependency-1 add a new common artifact...

Comment: I downloaded the example project from the jira issue and reproduced the problem. I have no explanation for the behaviour.